# How to run SUDO... commands in cronjobs in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts, cron

There are certain terminal commands which can only be run as a root user. If we try to execute them without **`sudo`** keyword, they fail with the **`Permission denied`** error. An example would be a command to make a directory/folder in certain locations.

I need to run one such command as a part of a cron job in my Ubuntu 16.04. Normally I could run the command with the **`sudo`** keyword in the terminal and I would be prompted to enter the root user's password and then the command would be executed successfully.

But now that I have to enter this command as a part of a cron job in my **`crontab`** file, how do I do this? How do I run such a command as a part of a cronjob?

Comment: `cron` runs with root. You don't need to add sudo.

Comment: Usually, one would put such jobs in root's crontab (`sudo crontab -e` rather than plain `crontab -e`) or use the system cron file `/etc/crontab` directly. Is there some particular reason you need to use a user crontab?

Comment: @steeldriver please what's the difference between `sudo crontab -e` and `crontab -e`?

Comment: @George `sudo crontab -e` inserts the command into root's crontab file `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`, whereas `crontab -e` inserts it into `$USER`'s crontab file `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER`

Comment: @steeldriver I guess my hunch was right!

Comment: I don't think CRON runs as root, @Pilot6 . If you add `* * * * * echo "hello" > /tmp/test.txt` to CronTab as normal user, the newly created file will have your username's owner, group and permissions.

Comment: You can't add anything to crontab "as normal user".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply run `crontab -e` as **root** user . This would run your command with *root* permission and there is no need to add  `sudo` before it .

However you can't login with *root* user and you need to perform your job as cron job you should specified full path in cron file :

```
 $ * * * * * /usr/bin/sudo /your/command
```

Also you can add `NOPASSWD` in front of your command in `/etc/sudoers` file to run command as *root* but without password .

Comment: There is no need for `sudo` since the task will run as root already.

Comment: @fkraiem As i said if you don't have access to root account for making new cron as root ,  you can use sudo .

Comment: If you have access to `sudo`, you typically have access to root.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to put it in the system-wide crontab at `/etc/crontab` (or in a file in `/etc/cron.d`), where you can specify the user each task is run at:

```
* * * * * root mkdir /foo/bar
```